# How to set a default dag trigger configuration json

Tags: airflow

When triggering a dag in airflow, there is a window, with which I am able to parameters to the dag in a json format. This looks like the following:
[image]

This json is always empty and I do have to know which parameters I can pass to the dag. Instead I would like to be able to prefill this json, so that when another user tries to trigger the dag he can simply change to values of the json, instead of having to look at the dags code first.

Is there any way to do this in the current version (2.0.0) of airflow?

Answer (score 14):

On Airflow 2.1.0  it is possible to set default arguments as follow:

```python
dag = DAG(dag_id="my_dag",
          schedule_interval=None,
          default_args={'retries': 3, 'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20)},
          catchup=False,
          tags=['maintenance'],
          params={"description": ""}  #Set parameters as a dictionary
)
```

In the thrigger UI it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is guide document : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/params.html

Answer (score 2):

When writing my feature request i actually found a pull request, which is already merged and seems to exactly do as described:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/10839

An improvement of the this feature also seems to be planned. See:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11054

Comment: did you manage to create a dag that uses this feature? If I'm understanding correctly it should just work by adding a params dictionary but I'm not able to get it working

Comment: @jmriego on Airflow 2.1.0 works like a charm. Gunder, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is currently not supported -- at least for Airflow 2.0.0

Comment: do you know, if there are any plans of introducing this feature?

Comment: No plans as of yet